# Mac Proxy Settings whitelisting for a particular URL

Tags: macos, proxy, whitelist

How do I set up SOCKS proxy for a particular URL on Mac OS?
Setting proxy in System Preferences sets it for all the sites.

Answer (score 0):

Use Firefox and the Foxyproxy addon